# Combining, filtering models/views in a ManyToMany Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm working on a comic book database and there are main covers and variant covers. I have a page that shows all the Main covers, but I'd like to combine the variant covers too, in order of the publication date. This is what part of my models look like:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Cover', 'Cover'),    
    ('Scan', 'Scan'),
    ('Other', 'Other'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Do not include the '#'.")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    ### The variant cover is determined by the category_choice 'Cover'. ###
    contributor = models.ManyToManyField(Contributor, blank=True, null=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

class Issue(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Major', 'Major'),    
    ('Minor', 'Minor'),
    ('Cameo', 'Cameo'),
    ('Other', 'Other'),
    )
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text="Do not include the '#'.")
    pub_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="covers/", blank=True, null=True)
    ### This would be where the main image goes. ^^^ ###
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, related_name="images_inc", blank=True, null=True)
    ### This is where the variant covers go.^^^  ### 
    has_emma = models.BooleanField(help_text="Check if Emma appears on the cover.")
```

My views.py for the main cover page looks like this:

```
def covers(request):
    sort_by = request.GET.get('sort', 'pub_date')
    if sort_by not in ['-date_added', 'date_added', '-pub_date', 'pub_date']:
        sort_by = '-date_added'
    issues = Issue.objects.filter(has_emma=True).order_by(sort_by).select_related(depth=1)
    return render_to_response('comics/covers.html', {'issues': issues}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But I would like to display the variant covers too and not just the `cover_image`. Is there a way to do this? Maybe with something `image` and then filtering the category (of the `Image` model by cover)?

I, of course, can do this:

```
def variants(request):
    Issue.objects.filter(has_emma=True).order_by(sort_by).select_related(depth=1)
    images = Image.objects.filter(category='Cover').order_by('id')
    return render_to_response('comics/variants.html', {'images': images}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But that does not give me enough flexibility as `def covers` does, and I want them combined and sorted by pub_date, like `def covers`.

**Edit**

models.py:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('Cover', 'Cover'),    
    ('Scan', 'Scan'),
    ('Other', 'Other'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=True)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']


class Issue(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ######
    has_emma = models.BooleanField(help_text="Check if cover appearance.")    
    cover_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="covers/", blank=True, null=True)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, related_name="images_inc", blank=True, null=True)
    ######
    def get_images(self):
        ''' Returns a list of all cover images combined,
            "main" cover image first.
        '''
        images = [self.cover_image]
        for image in self.images.filter(category='Cover'):
            images.append(image.image)
        return images
```

views.py:

```
def covers(request):
    sort_by = request.GET.get('sort', '-pub_date')
    if sort_by not in ['-date_added', 'date_added', '-pub_date', 'pub_date']:
        sort_by = '-date_added'         
    issues = Issue.objects.filter(has_emma=True).order_by(sort_by)
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'issues': issues,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template.html:
`{% for issue in issues %}{% for image in issue.get_images %}{{ image.image }}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}` - displays nothing, however, `{% for issue in issues %} {% for image in issue.get_images %} {{ issue.cover_image }} {% endfor %} {% endfor %}` will **repeatedly** display the `cover_image` of the `Issue` model if there are variant covers, which are categorized in the `Image` model.

What can I do to fix this, so that it shows everything correctly? And for the record again, I want it to display the `{{ cover_image }}` (from the `Issue` model) and the `{{ image.image }}` as defined by the `Image` model combined.

Comment: Am I correct that your problem that you can't access variant images in the template rendered by the `covers()` view?

Comment: I'd like to access variant images (`images = ManyToManyField(Image)` with category = Cover) and have them combined with `cover_image` for the template so that it will be sorted by `pub_date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, one way to solve it would be adding a method to `Issue` class like this:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    # fields...

    def get_images(self):
        ''' Returns a list of all cover images combined,
            "main" cover image first.
        '''
        images = [self.cover_image]
        for image in self.images.filter(category='Cover'):
            images.append(image.image)
        return images
```

Then, in your template, you can do, for example, `{% for image in issue.get_images %}...`.

(If it's not exactly what you need—then, I think, it would be better if you provide some template code as an example of what you're trying to achieve.)

Comment: Like this?    `{% for image in issue.get_images %}<li><img src="{% if image.image %}{% thumbnail image.image 94x150 %}{% else %}(thumbnail){% endif %}" alt="{{ issue }}" width="94" height="150"/></li>{% endfor %}`    And I'm just hoping the combined images will sort by publication date, as defined by the issue model.

Comment: Yes, this way you'll output all images for given issue, but what do you mean by sorting combined images by publication date? There's no such field on `Image` model, only on `Issue`... Do you maybe mean that images should be sorted by `date_added`?

Comment: The template tag I showed above isn't displaying anything. And, yes, I have `date_added` but I was hoping I could somehow connect `pub_date` on the `Issue` model through the ManyToMany `Image`. Is that possible?

Comment: The above example shows how to get the images of _one_ particular issue. You're supposed to use it in the nested loop, like that: `{% for issue in issues %}{% for image in issue.get_images %}<...>{% endfor %}{% endfor %}`. If you have different requirements, please update the question with what your template code is supposed to look like.

Comment: Hi, delayed response. This is almost working when I do this: `{% for issue in issues %}
{% for image in issue.get_images %}
<li>{{ issue.cover_image }} </li>  
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}` It's correct in that it kind of shows the `cover_image` and the variants through the M2M (but it repeats the `cover_image` if there is a variant, of course). However, when I do `{{ image.image }}`, it displays nothing. Am I doing something wrong with my template code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `{{ image.image }}` should output a path to image file. If it outputs nothing, then either `image` field is empty on current Image, or you are referencing wrong `{{ image }}` in template. If you post more of your template code which is relevant to the problem and describe it in more detail, that could help.

Comment: OK, I edited the original post, so you can check it out. It's under **Edit**.

Comment: Oh, I meant more of the _template code_, not models and views… Okay, I think I see where's the problem. Try changing `{{ issue.cover_image }}` to `{{ image }}`. That's because `get_images()` method in the answer is outputting a list of _image paths_, not the Image model instances. I've missed that in your first comment, too: `image.image` is incorrect, should be `{% thumbnail image ... %}`.

Comment: Works great, thanks! And that was all the template code I have. I included the models and views in case there was anything missing. Thanks again.